# replaceWith on element that has already been replaced

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

I'm fully aware that when you use `replaceWith()` it removes the element from the DOM and replaces it, but how do I pass the newly created element so that it can be replaced again?

For example, I have an icon that has an `onclick=""` event like so

```
<i onclick="toggleStatus(true, this, '.$user->id.')" class="icon-red fas fa-times"></i>
```

It then runs the following function, which replaces the icon with a loading wheel. As the new loading wheel replaces this element in the DOM, how do i pass the newly created loading wheel so that it can be replaced again?

This is what I have so far

```
window.toggleStatus = function(status, elem, id){
    var $i = $(elem);
    //Replace the icon with a spinning wheel for effect

    $i.removeClass().addClass('fa fa-spinner animation-spinning');

    setTimeout(function(){
       if(status){
            $i.removeClass('fa fa-spinner animation-spinning').addClass('direct-debit-icon icon-green fas fa-check').attr('onclick','toggleStatus(false, this, '+id+')');
       } else {
            $i.removeClass('fa fa-spinner animation-spinning').addClass('direct-debit-icon icon-red fas fa-times').attr('onclick','toggleStatus(true, this, '+id+')');
       }
    },1000);
}
```

**Note** I have to use `replaceWith()` and cannot just alter the elements classes as im using Font Awesome 5 so the `<i>` elements get replaced with SVG's like this

```
<svg onclick="toggleStatus(false, this, 1)" class="svg-inline--fa fa-check fa-w-16" aria-hidden="true" data-prefix="fa" data-icon="check" role="img" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 512 512" data-fa-i2svg=""><path fill="currentColor" d="M173.898 439.404l-166.4-166.4c-9.997-9.997-9.997-26.206 0-36.204l36.203-36.204c9.997-9.998 26.207-9.998 36.204 0L192 312.69 432.095 72.596c9.997-9.997 26.207-9.997 36.204 0l36.203 36.204c9.997 9.997 9.997 26.206 0 36.204l-294.4 294.401c-9.998 9.997-26.207 9.997-36.204-.001z"></path></svg>
```

**This question has been edited in relation to one of the answers and its comments below**

Comment: You don't need to replace the element at all. Given your logic you can just amend the classes on the single `<i>` instance using add/remove/toggle class. Also note that you should be using unobtrusive event handlers (especially as you've included jQuery in the page already) instead of the outdated `on*` event attributes

Comment: This is an option, I just thought replacing it would be a cleaner way that replacing the classes and the onclick data

Comment: It's almost exactly the opposite. If you change the classes then you don't need to amend the event handler at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to replace the element at all. Given your logic you can just amend the classes on the single `<i>` instance using add/remove/toggle class.

Also note that you should be using unobtrusive event handlers (especially as you've included jQuery in the page already) instead of the outdated `on*` event attributes.

With all that said, try this:

```js
$('i').click(function() {
  var $i = $(this);
  var userId = $i.data('userid');
  console.log(userId);
  
  $i.removeClass('icon-red icon-green fa-check fa-times').addClass('fa-spinner fa-spin');
  
  var status = Math.random() > 0.5; // just for testing
  setTimeout(function() {
    $i.removeClass('fa-spinner fa-spin');
    if (status) {
      $i.addClass('icon-green fa-check')
    } else {
      $i.addClass('icon-red fa-times');
    }
  }, 1000);
});
```

```css
.icon-red { color: #C00; }
.icon-green { color: #0C0; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.2.0/css/all.css" />

<i data-userid="abc-123" class="icon-red fas fa-times"></i>
<i data-userid="zxy-987" class="icon-red fas fa-times"></i>
```

Note that the above is using Font Awesome v5, so the `animation-spinning` class has been changed to `fa-spin`

Comment: Just realised something. I have to use replaceWith as im using Font awesome 5 so the elements are converted to SVG's. I'll amend my question now.

Comment: This is also using FA5

Comment: Its not working for me and I have no idea why, I will update my question with the 'toggleStatus' function

Comment: No errors, I have updated my question. It replaces with the spinning icon fine, but then it won't replace with the new check or cross icon

Comment: The code in your question has an obvious syntax error which will have shown up in the console; you're missing a `)` after the first `attr()` call. *However*, why are you even doing that? The whole point of the answer I gave you above was to avoid needing the `onclick` ugliness

Comment: I have noticed that the classes are replacing correctly, so if i log the element and look at its class list, it is adding the classes correctly. Its just not actually showing the new icon. Even if I run `$('my>svg>element>selector').removeClass('fa-spinner animation-spinning')` in the console. It still shows the spinning icon and will not update

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/178069/discussion-between-s-r-and-rory-mccrossan).

Comment: That's because SVG follows different patterns when updating classes. Don't use it. As I've shown you above, you don't need to at all.